# Unity+Vuforia project migration issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

We have project on unity 2018.2.20f and vuforia 7.5.26, New google play requirements(x64) need upgrade unity and vuforia. We Install unity 2018.4.6LTS and vuforia 8.3.8 and have problems with tracking https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtmdkIARPoY . But if i create empty project on 2018.4.6 and use vuforia 8.3.8 i dont have this problems. I tried delete all vuforia asset and reimoptr - didn help, i try delete temp\librarry folder - didnt help. I dont know what to do. Help pls

Comment: And what are those exceptions and warnings you are getting?

Comment: error its a problems in materials from assetbundle. Warning, message of loading. Its custom. has nothing to do with vuforia